# how to make ticket list clear after getting in to it second time from menu button in xamarin forms for ios?

Tags: ios, xamarin

The iOS Application have menu button which contains list of events. In the list there is a event of showing a list. And list can be access directly form the main page by clicking on navigation icon(on navigation bar) for list.

The first time I click on list from menu page it works fine but second time it shows a result from last visit. It appears on the top of the list.

So, I have to remove the result which appear in top of list for second time.

It only happens in iOS. Same code for android doesn't give any problem.

Comment: Hi welcome to SO, When posting a question you should provide relevant snippets of code so people can try help. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask is a good resource on how to ask a good question

Comment: Without seeing any of your code it's just conjecture.
But I think you are adding "ticket" to your list when it appears.
On the second time, the list will still have the old ticket stored in it.
So clear it before adding the items to it